# How to make a GUI out of a already done code in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I want to make a GUI . I have a code that runs, made in C++. The project is made in Visual Studio(Visual C++ 2010 Express).

The outputs now are printed in command line. I want to tranform this to be printed to a window.

Is there a way to do this in this already made project ? Or I have to make a new one.

**P.S.** The code is consists of many, about **20** .cpp files and about **5** .h headers.

Comment: Simply turn your "cout << ...." calls (or printf if the code is actually C) to append the text to the UI control you want the output to be displayed in?

Or you can check this "hack" out: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/27876/

Comment: @ExtremeCoder How can I make a simple window in this project? How can I recognize if this is a cli project or a windows form project?

Comment: @georgemano If it is C++, then it is not CLI or windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment on your original post here's some more information that will help you get through this:

> Simply turn your "cout << ...." calls (or printf if the code is
>   actually C) to append the text to the UI control you want the output
>   to be displayed in? Or you can check this "hack" out:
>   cplusplus.com/forum/general/27876

Now simply add a new source file to the project: call it.. MyProjectGUI.cpp

Follow this guide here to setup the window on your project:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx

Then go through the rest of your code (or use the hack mentioned above or some kind of pipe to redirect your output (probably a lot! more complicated than the following method) and simply replace your `cout << / printf` calls with something like what's detailed in here: http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/windows/105327/105327/appending-text-to-edit-control/

You'll find the basic idea of your modifications to be along these lines:

1. Create a simple window
2. Add a new edit field to the window (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/User_Interface_Controls and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. Replace all console printing calls with a call to your append function for the edit box in the GUI

Best of luck with this (I might write up some code if I'm bothered but don't count on it -> no time. You should be able to figure it out with what I've posted though)

Answer (score -1):

You dont have to do another project. It is enough to include headers and add libraries to linker.  You should try a QT which is portable, well written and easy to learn. My one advice is to stay as portable as possible, in example you can create a makefile for your project so add new libraries will be a quiet easy job and not related to IDE .  Dont stick to one environment.

Comment: What is a linker? Where do I find it? I prefer to stick to the visual studio environment. I believe I will stuck easily in new stuff.

Comment: " linker or link editor is a program that takes one or more objects generated by a compiler and combines them into a single executable program." You should change IDE to learn what is linker. For the very beginning i recommend you a codeblocks with GCC. It will help you to understand basic schema of creating C/C++ application.

Comment: While I agree with learning how C++ actually gets built and linked, I don't agree with your sentiment of "stop using tools that make development easier and just use GCC and makefiles." You can learn about linkers just as easily with VC++ as with Code::Blocks.

Comment: @Nicol Any suggestion Nicol how to make a GUI inside this VS project?

Comment: @georgemano: If you don't know what a linker is, I would suggest trying to learn more about how C++ is compiled and built before trying to learn about GUI issues. You're simply not read for it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I read and I know what is a linker. I understood that I have dont that at the university. The point is dont know now how to continue. The toolbox in VS does not show anything link a window, a dropdown-menu. I have done GUIs with C# and I know that there is a way with C++.

Comment: @georgemano Unless your university is using a C++ interpreter (extremely unlikely), then they most certainly are providing you with a linker. As others have suggested, you should really learn some C++ basics. Of course there is a way to write a GUI in C++, but you will need to use an external library (of which there are many to pick from) as the language itself and the standard library do not contain any GUI frameworks. This answer has suggested using Qt, but there are many others - just google "C++ GUI library".